# Excluding 0s from a contingency table made from subset data in R

Tags: r, subset, contingency

I'm new to stack overflow so please let me know if you need more information.

I'm was workking with a dataset which contained two options for the variable "colour" and then two each for "shade". I subsetted the data thus:

```
blue <- subset(data1, colour=="B")
```

which seemed to work and only colour "B" and shade "sky" and "navy" remained when I typed in "blue"

I then wanted to create a contingency table from this subset which I did thus:

```
table1 <-table(blue$shade, blue$Response)
```

where response is a Y/N.

However at this point I ran into problems as the red shades reappeared with 0s in my contingency table

```
               Y    N
Sky            35   8
Navy           36   12
Scarlet        0    0
Maroon         0    0
```

Can anyone advise on how to remove these 0 values aside from "fix"ing the table and manually deleting the relevant parts?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `droplevels` to remove the unused levels

```
blue <- droplevels(blue)
```

and then do the `table`

```
table(blue$shade, blue$Response)
```